# What is the value of the second derivative of a probability generating function?

Tags: probability, generating-functions

We have a generating function

$$G(\eta)$$

so $$G(1)=\Sigma_rP(X=r)=1$$ (I get this)
and $$G^\prime(1)=\Sigma_rrP(x=r)=E(X)$$ (I also get this)
And I understand why:
$$G^{\prime\prime}(1)=\Sigma_rr(r-1)P(x=r)$$
But I don't understand/follow this:
$$\Sigma_rr(r-1)P(x=r)=E(X(X-1))$$
Could someone tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By ["unconscious" computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician), we have the general formula
$$E[f(X)] = \sum_r f(r) P(X=r),$$
so with the special case $f(r)=r(r-1)$ we have
$$E[X(X-1)] = \sum_r r(r-1) P(X=r).$$